# Как получить все обработчики события из EventInfo?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как через рефлексию получить все обработчики события? Ведь, когда я добавляю обработчик, он должен сохраняться в какое-то приватное поле.

Answer (score 0):

Класс для получения списка делегатов для обычных классов (не наследников от класса `Component`

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public static class ReflectionHelper
    {
        public static Delegate[] GetSubscribedMethods(object instance, string eventName)
        {
            var type = instance.GetType();
            var currentEvent = type.GetEvents().FirstOrDefault(ev => ev.Name == eventName);
            if (currentEvent != null)
            {
                var eventFieldInfo = type.GetField(eventName,
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField);

                if (eventFieldInfo != null)
                {
                    var eventFieldValue = (Delegate)eventFieldInfo.GetValue(instance);
                    return eventFieldValue.GetInvocationList();
                }
            }

            return new Delegate[0];
        }
    }
}
```

И код с демонстрацией работы

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private readonly Worker _worker;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load += OnMainFormLoad;

            _worker = new Worker();
            _worker.SomeEvent1 += OnWorkerSomeEvent11;
            _worker.SomeEvent1 += OnWorkerSomeEvent12;
            _worker.SomeEvent2 += OnWorkerSomeEvent22;
        }

        private void OnWorkerSomeEvent11(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void OnWorkerSomeEvent12(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void OnWorkerSomeEvent22(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void OnMainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var clickEventHandlers = ReflectionHelper.GetSubscribedMethods(
                _worker, nameof(Worker.SomeEvent1));

            var lostFocusEventHandlers = ReflectionHelper.GetSubscribedMethods(
                _worker, nameof(Worker.SomeEvent2));
        }
    }

    public class Worker
    {
        public event EventHandler SomeEvent1;
        public event EventHandler SomeEvent2;

        public void DoWork()
        {
            SomeEvent1?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            SomeEvent2?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

На примере `Windows Forms` приложения и кнопки

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load += OnMainFormLoad;
            execButton.Click += OnButtonClick1;
            execButton.Click += OnButtonClick2;
            execButton.LostFocus += OButtonLostFocus;
        }

        private static Delegate[] GetInvocationListOfEvent(Control control, string eventName)
        {
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(Control).GetField(
                "Event" + eventName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            if (fieldInfo != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = control.GetType().GetProperty("Events",
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

                if (pi != null)
                {
                    var list = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(control, null);
                    object obj = fieldInfo.GetValue(control);
                    return list[obj].GetInvocationList();
                }
            }

            return new Delegate[0];
        }

        private void OnMainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var clickEventHandlers = GetInvocationListOfEvent(
                execButton, nameof(Control.Click));

            var lostFocusEventHandlers = GetInvocationListOfEvent(
                execButton, nameof(Control.LostFocus));
        }

        private void OButtonLostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void OnButtonClick1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void OnButtonClick2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приватное свойство Events существует у любого объекта или только у контрола?

Comment: Оно объявлено в классе Component, от которого унаследован уже Control.

Comment: А как это выполнить, если объект не наследуется от него?

Comment: @Antinet, обновил ответ. Добавлен ещё один вариант.

Comment: Строка var eventFieldInfo = type.GetField(eventName,
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField); возвращает null.

Comment: В моём примере возвращает то, что мы ожидаем (не null). Твоего кода я не видел, в котором это не работает, так что сказать ничего не могу. Можешь выложить код на какой-нибудь хостинг кода и дать ссылку в комментариях.

Comment: var b = new Button();
            b.Click += (s, args) => {  };
            MessageBox.Show(GetSubscribedMethods(b, "Click")[0].Method.ToString());

Это уже приводит к ошибке выхода за границы массива.

Comment: @Antinet, для получения списка обработчиков события у наследника от Component (в твоём случае это Button) есть другой вариант, который я изначально выложил.

Comment: А есть универсальный вариант для наследников и обычных?

Comment: @Antinet есть. Создаёшь третий метод, в котором проверяешь, если это наследник от Component (или даже Control). то вызываешь метод для Control, если нет, то вызываешь другой метод. Возможно, что есть какой-то способ, но у меня нет времени с этим разбираться сейчас.